# pages not changing when changing user group in liferay 6

Tags: liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6

I am using Liferay and I have created 3 user groups. My application is like ,the user will be able to switch user groups in the UI using a drop down. When I login for a specific user group the pages are visible according to user group.

But when I switch user groups, the pages do not change according to user groups. Logs show that the change in user group is detected. The same was working in liferay 5. Please suggest what has to be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you detecting change in user group? what action you are performing on dropdown selection?

Comment: More details please: Do you have different sites that each usergroup is member of? What have you customized in order to make the usergroup selectable on login? (or after login?). What's the visibility of the pages that you see once logged in? Do you expect to utilize Liferay's permission framework for the display of pages or can everybody always see everything and you're just referring to the pages displayed by default?

Comment: On click I get the details for new login, I logout and login with new credentiaals.

Comment: sorry, this was a code issue. THanks for your replies.